# How does TableLayout work with TableRow?

Tags: java, android

I have a TableLayout filled programmatically while scrolling a cursor. I create 3 items every cursor step: TextView, ImageView and TextView. My problem is with the ImageView.

On ImageView I wanna draw a ShapeDrawable (for that I have overridden a View like [2D Graphics - Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)).

On ImageView I set a background resource (to apply shape properties) with a drawable XML file. For that I want the height to differ from the other TextView on the same TableRow.

I tried various combinations (setting LayoutParams, gravity, layout_weight) without success. The result is always the same: the ImageView is the same height as the TableRow.

Here some pieces of code:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_show_stats);
tl.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
tl.setColumnShrinkable(0, true);

for every cursor step
  TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
  TableRow.LayoutParams tr_lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  tr.setLayoutParams(tr_lp);
  tr.setBaselineAligned(true);

  TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
  LayoutParams tv1lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1L);
  tv1lp.column = 0;
  tv1lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
  tv1.setLayoutParams(tv1lp);
  tv1.setText(" description ");

  ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
  CustomImgBarDrawableView dw = new CustomImgBarDrawableView(this, width, height);
  img.setImageDrawable(dw.mDrawable);
  LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1L);
  lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
  lp.column = 1;
  img.setLayoutParams(lp);
  img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout_showbar);

  TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
  LayoutParams tv2lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1L);
  tv2lp.column = 2;
  tv2lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
  tv2.setLayoutParams(tv2lp);
  tv2.setText(" value ");

  tr.addView(tv1);
  tr.addView(img);
  tr.addView(tv2);
  tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))




public class CustomImgBarDrawableView extends View {
  private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
  public CustomImgBarDrawableView(Context context, int w, int h) {
    super(context);
    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    mDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(h);
    mDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(w);
  }
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway.
I have found another solution.
For to show a progressive value, instead of single ImageView with defined dimensions,
I use a horizontal LinearLayout with x-many ImageView fill-fill.
So I have solved my problem of positioning, delegating Android the work of correctly fill the space.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have found another solution but you can use

```
img.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(width,height));
```